# AgglomerativeClustering scikit learn connectivity

Tags: scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering, unsupervised-learning

```
I have a matrix x=  
[[0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
[1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0],
[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1],
[0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1],
[0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0],]
```

After calling **AgglomerativeClustering** I was expecting the data to be divided   into 2 clusters **(0-3) and (4-7) i.e labels_=[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1] but insted the  labels_ list is [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]**

My code is as follows   `s=AgglomerativeClustering(affinity='precomputed',n_clusters=2,linkage='complete)
s.fit(x)`

Does the code contain any error? Why is the clustering not as expected

Comment: Is it sample matrix or connectivity matrix? If you delete affinity parameter you will achieve desired results.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me, after playing around with a few examples, that `AgglomerativeClustering` interprets the 'affinity' matrix as a distance matrix, although I can't find this specified anywhere. This means that your 0's and 1's should be switched.

Also it only seems to consider the upper triangular portion of the matrix (everything else being redundant).

I believe that defining `x` as:

```
x=  
[[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
[ 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
[ 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
[ 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],]
```

will give you the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in how you are specifying the connectivity matrix. From your description, I assume that your matrix indicates linkage between points, where [0/1] indicate [no link/link]. However, the algorithm treats this as a matrix of *pairwise distances*, which is why you get unexpected results.

You could convert your affinity matrix to a sort of distance matrix with a simple transform; e.g.

```
>>> x = np.array(x)
>>> s.fit(np.exp(-x))
>>> s.labels_
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Better would be to use an actual distance metric on the data used to generate this affinity matrix.